# how to block git from allowing unauthenticated user to make git changes

Tags: ssh, git

I have several different git users each for different git repos and each with a different ssh key pair and each git user has its own version of file `~/.gitconfig` yet sometimes I mistakenly issue

```
git add foo
```

using wrong git user ( wrong file sym linked to file `~/.gitconfig` ) which cuts changes to a given git repo visible from

```
git log
```

which I want to avoid ... `git push` correctly fails yet `git add` can be performed by an unauthenticated git user

I only authenticate to a git repo using ssh keys ... to toggle between different git users I remove then recreate symbolic link

```
~/.gitconfig
```

to point to one of the various git config files specific to a given git user all of which are similar to

```
[user]
    email = example@gmail.com
    name = Hare Bere
[color]
    ui = true
[push]
    default = simple
[alias]
    co = checkout

[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/


[core]
    sshcommand=ssh -i ~/.ssh/foobar

[pull]
    rebase = false
```

to toggle between various git users I change what file `~/.gitconfig` points to then I run

```
ssh-add  path-to-ssh-key
```

I am on a Ubuntu laptop

What am I missing to isolate each git user from being able to issue git commands against wrong repo ?

Comment: “I have several different git users each for different git repos and each with a different ssh key pair…” Why are you doing this? Work related? Because if you work for multiple places and want to commit under different accounts (work versus home) that makes sense. But otherwise, this seems like a lot of overcomplexity for one person.

Comment: I'm confused. `git add` does not use your identity. Only creating commits does. // Why not just set the identity inside the repository configuration? That's what Git's config levels are there for.